# How are multibit logic gate made?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

I'm doing a lab about building an ALU. One of the instructions I'm supposed to make is A⨁B, however, A and B are 4-bits long but I've ever only learned about XOR taking 2 inputs.

So I'm wondering does A and B travel in serial and each pair of bits gets calculated at a time or is there some special circuit you can build to XOR multiple bits at once?

Also the simulator has adders that takes in multiple bits as well. Usually I learn that the adders can be combined to take in multiple bits input in parallel. So if InA and InB moves in the adder in series then is there a circuit inside the adder that converts the serial input to parallel input?

[image]

Comment: are you certain that InA ans InB are serial inputs?

Comment: I'm not sure, that's how they're shown in Logisim which is where my confusion lies.

Comment: There are whole books and half of an university exam (multiplier networks I'm looking at you) on the subject, especially for arithmetica. The 'easy' way is to parallelize and use ripple carries but there are clever methods to optimize the process. Logic functions have no carry and are simples but there are many way to do it, too

Answer (score 2):

You can handle multi-bit words in parallel or serial, or a combination of both. That's an implementation choice, that's made before the detail design is started.

If you want a high throughput device, then you would choose parallel. It would be large and consume relatively high power. If you want a cheaper smaller lower power device, maybe you're building a pocket calculator, then you might choose an all serial implementation.

Generally an all serial implementation keeps everything serial, there's little point otherwise. An adder would add the LSBs and previous carry and save the carry bit on each clock pulse, until the whole word had shifted through the adder. That's one of the flexibilities of the serial model, the word width depends only on the depth of your serial memories.

There are also hybrid schemes, where you might handle (say) 4 or 8 bits in parallel, and handle as many of those in serial as needed for your word width, but that would be used for fine-tuning an implementation to fit a particular power speed or chip area budget.

In the lab, I'd expect everybody to get an all serial and an all parallel exercise, and the more capable students would also tackle a hybrid one.

Comment: great explanation. thanks!